# cut matched and put in another location

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

How can i cut numbers that are inside square brackets and put them at the begining of text?

for example:

```
some_text123_[12345]_some_text

after:
12345_some_text123_[]_some_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `perl`.

This perl one liner should work.

```
$ echo some_text123_[123]_some_text | perl -ne 'print "$1_", "$`", "$'\''\n" if /\[(\d+?)\]/;' -
```

Just to explain the special variable from perl regex engine:

$1 - its what I wanna preserve on matching.

$` - its everything before match

$' - its everything after match

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sed`, matching:

1. A group of characters
2. A bracket, then numbers, then another bracket
3. Another group of characters

The regex could be `(.*) (\[[0-9]+\]) (.*)` (without the spaces). Then, substitute the match with the groups in `2-1-3` order.

```
$ echo "some_text_[12345]_some_text" | sed "s_(.*)\[([0-9]+)\](.*)_\2\1[]\3_g"
12345some_text_[]_some_text
```

Comment: i'm getting sed: -e expression #1, char 33: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: You shouldn't be, unless you're missing a `( \ "`

Comment: did a copy paste of your example `echo "some_text_[12345]_some_text" | sed "s_(.*)\[([0-9]+)\](.*)_\2\1[]\3_g"`

Comment: Oh, try it with `sed -E`, I have an alias

Answer (score 1):

Here's another sed variation, using the hold space to move things around. Not that it's the best way, but it's kind of fun.

```
sed -e 'h;s/.*\[\([0-9]*\)\].*/\1/;x;s/\[.*\]/[]/;H;g;s/\n//'
```

The h command copies the current line into the hold space. Then we isolate the numbers between [ and ]. The x swaps the numbers for the original line, so the hold space has the numbers only. Then we discard everything between the [] this time and append the result to the numbers in the hold space. Get the hold space back (g), remove the embedded newline, and there you go.

```
$ echo "some_text123_[12345]_some_text" | sed -e 'h;s/.*\[\([0-9]*\)\].*/\1/;x;s/\[.*\]/[]/;H;g;s/\n//'
12345some_text123_[]_some_text
```